PMSM motor drive analog control loop
Specifications of pmsm servo motor:300W 200VAC
Encoder:2000 ppr
I am tasked with fabricating a servo drive for the above said motor,which is used to drive rotary table(1:50 gear reduction).Indexing accuracy needed for rotary table 0.001 deg
I can program to a extent in assembly and c for small microcontrollers,but DSP is not my forte,since the power of motor is only moderate,i decided to implement the position and speed control loop with microcontroller and current control in analog way.FOC is the targeted method to be implemented.
My question: is it correct /reliable way to implement Park Clarke and their inverse transformation with multiplying dac and opamp alone(due to bandwidth constraint in microcontroller)
Chain of control
Encoder--up/down counter--Static ram--MDAC and opamp(for coordinate transformation and PI current control)
I know what I asked is pretty vague without the further details like control bandwidth ,desired motion speed acceleration and other stuff.I am just bit skeptical about going with analog circuit for transformation and PI control,so wanted to get opinion about that,planning to use 12 bit DAC,application will be suffice with 8 bit accuracy

I know what I asked is pretty vague without the further details like control bandwidth ,desired motion speed acceleration and other stuff.I am just bit skeptical about going with analog circuit for transformation and PI control,so wanted to get opinion about that,planning to use 12 bit DAC,application will be suffice with 8 bit accuracy

You should move your comment to your post, as it further explains your question.

Do you expect backlash in the gearbox?

I haven't opened the gear assembly,but gear at the motor shaft was usual ratio gear,so yes I would expect a backlash

What do you mean by 'current control in analog way'? PI controllers using opamps for FOC especially current controllers can be tricky as their gain calculations are mostly opamp dependent. A better solution would be to use ready made FOC controllers which do all the heavy lifting (clarke,parke, svm etc) for you..Ex: A89301

@AK47 i meant to say the inner most loop in motor control,which will be current control loop needing a fast settling time,which translates a faster adc and even faster micro processor/dedicated DSP,A89301 meant for BLDC and it is based on sensorless algorithm,better suited for speed control,mine is industrial system with sensored position control
